# Software to setup cron jobs programmatically

Tags: linux, task-management

cronie, dcron, frcon and bron all lack an api to set up a cron job from a script easily. Is there a cronjob manager that can be setup manually but also using an API. Something that could take a file like the following:

job:

```
   env: 
       MYVAR: /home/usr/:/mnt/shared/libraries/so/
   script: /home/user/myjob.sh
   time:
       minute: 30
       hour: 18
       day: *
       month: *
       year:*
   error-output: /home/user/cron.error.log
   std-output: /home/user/cron.log
```

(Whatever markup language is preferred) and turn it into a cronjob.

Comment: What about simple bash ? https://askubuntu.com/a/58582/631600 or https://askubuntu.com/a/589800/631600

Comment: As RoVo commented, please edit your Question to explain what you are looking for that can't be done with shell scripts.